# Powershell where-object speed improvement

Tags: windows-server-2012, powershell, dhcp

I want to get a list of my DHCP reservations from my DHCP Server running Windows Server 2012R2. The list should contain the IP, MAC, name, description and the lease status of the reservation (just to check if the client is online or not). I know there's a CMDLet to get the reservations.

```
$IP_res = (Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ScopeId 10.10.0.0)
```

The result doesn't contain the lease status. But there is another CMDLet to get it:

```
$IP_lease =(Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ScopeId 10.10.0.0)
```

Now my idea was to build a custom object wich contains all the atributes I need.

```
$save =  New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
foreach($line in $IP_res)
{
   $new_IP_Obj = "" | Select IP, MAC, Name, Description, LeaseStatus
   $var = $IP_lease | Where-Object {$_.ClientId -eq $line.ClientId } 
   $new_IP_Obj.IP = $line.IPAddress.IPAddressToString
   $new_IP_Obj.MAC = $line.ClientId
   $new_IP_Obj.Name = $line.Name
   $new_IP_Obj.Description = $line.Description 
   $new_IP_Obj.LeaseStatus = $var.AddressState
   $save.add(new_IP_obj)
}
```

Unfortunately Where-Object is quite slow when you need to compare huge data. 
Is there any chance to improve the speed of where-object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a code I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026126/powershell-combine-two-hash-tables) and modified for this.

```
$Merged = @()
$Scopes = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName dc2008 #-ScopeId '10.1.230.0'
Foreach ($Scope In $Scopes) {
    $IP_res = (Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ComputerName dc2008 -ScopeId $Scope.ScopeId)
    $IP_lease =(Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName dc2008 -ScopeId $Scope.ScopeId)

    $IP_lease + $IP_res | Group-Object -Property ClientId | ForEach {
        If ($_.group[1].AddressState -ne $null) {
            $Record = New-Object -TypeName psCustomObject -Property @{
                IP=$_.group[0].IPAddress.IPAddressToString;
                MAC=$_.group[0].ClientId;
                Name=$_.group[1].Name;
                Description=$_.group[0].Description;
                LeaseStatus=$_.group[1].AddressState
                };
            $Merged += $Record
        }
    }
}
$Merged | ft -AutoSize
```

Though I can't prove it, I'm inclined to think that Group-Object is a faster method (because it receives both lists, he can use faster search methods, unlike 'where' who receives a list and one item to find).

Comment: OK, so what are the results?

Comment: I did some time measuring with my original code and the adjusted code with your suggestion. The average time for 5 executions with my and your code in seconds are: original: 125,8s ; adjusted: 14,2s That's nearly 10 times faster ! Great job, thanks ! –

Comment: There is a way to improve even this. You only need to create System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object] instead of a single array. Then you can add $record to the list. This makes it even faster :)